# Xcode refactoring options grayed out

Tags: xcode, xcode15

Usually the only options that is available is "Rename", but I would also like to be able to refactor methods so that each parameter is on a separate line.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

// Dummy text to reach 220 character count

Answer (score 1):

To move each parameter to a separate line put the cursor on the first line and press ⌃M

Comment: Wait... what...? OMG! This works! How did I not know this! So many times I've gone through each line in turn to add it to the next line. LOL! Thank you for this!

Comment: It's new in Xcode 15. I saw it in some WWDC or What's-new-in-Xcode video.